# can we integrate PWA into flutter application like webview?

Tags: flutter, webview, progressive-web-apps

Is it possible to integrate PWA apps into flutter applications like displaying web applications through `webview` in flutter. Can we display the complete PWA app inside a flutter application?

Comment: What with it be the use case for that? You'll be affecting performance to gain nothing. PWA are ment to be standalone web apps using Flutter itself and not inside a WebView inside Flutter.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you create flutter web application it automatically creates a PWA and you can notice it will you launch the website on the phone.

And inside webview if you load a website it will load. In this case it does not matter whether it is PWA .

PWA a just extra functionality that creates a wrapper to install the app in different platform

Answer (score 0):

Flutter supports deploying the web version as a PWA, the details are in their [documentation](https://flutter.dev/web), search for `A Progressive Web Application built with Flutter`